# Graphing a function f(x,y) on a restricted set of values for (x,y)

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, mathematica

I'm having a hard time with this certain problem.

Suppose that $S=\{(x,y): x^2 + y^2\leq 4\}$ and define $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as
$f(x,y)=-x-2y-2y^2+cos(x\pi /4)$.

How can we produce a (3d) plot, in MATLAB or Mathematica, that shows whether this function is convex or concave (or neither)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Consider cross-posting on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab this can be done by combining `meshgrid` and `pol2cart`:

```
th = linspace(0,2*pi,40);
r = linspace(0,4,20);
[TH,R] = meshgrid(th,r);
[X,Y] = pol2cart(TH,R);
Z = -X-2*Y-2*Y.^2+cos(X*pi/4);
surf(X,Y,Z)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

Comment: Thank you very very much @horchler, this solution is actually very helpful to get into such problems.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5B-x-2y-2y%5E2%2bCos%5Bx%2aPi/4%5D,%20%7Bx,-2,2%7D,%7By,-2,2%7D%5D) is the plot using wolfram alpha over $[0,2]^2$:

Clearly looks concave.

Comment: It does prove whether it is concave or convex or neither, but it's not exactly what I wanted to graph.

The set S is a circle, whereas $K=[0,2]^2$ is a square. Since $f$ is concave on $K$ then it will of course be so on $S\subset K$, but the graph I need to plot is specifically on $S$.
Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @Emil exactly, i went for plotting over the box because it would possible imply over any subset...